# Is Notification Setting really important?

Tags: web, notification, app

I have a project that will give reminder notification to the customers which will send a message to the phone and email, I'm currently thinking about adding a notification setting page to the app. I'm curious about this turn on/turn off function for notification in my app, is that really important to have this setting page if I have notification feature in the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material design has a very complete section on [Notification patterns](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-types-of-notifications).

> **Types of notifications**
>
> Notifications are considered either transactional or non-transactional.
>
> **Transactional**
>
> Transactional notifications provide content that a user must receive at a specific time in order to do one of the following:
>
> - Enable human-to-human interaction
> - Function better in daily life
> - Control or resolve transient device states
>
> **Non-transactional**
>
> If none of the above situations describe your notification, then it is non-transactional.
>
> **Non-transactional opt-out and opt-in**
>
> Non-transactional notifications should be optional, as they may not appeal to all users. You can make them optional in one of two ways:
>
> - **Opt-out**: Users receive opt-out notifications by default, but they may stop receiving them by turning off a setting.
> - **Opt-in**: Users only receive opt-in notifications by turning on a setting in your app.

As you can see depending on the kind of notification they suggest the way to make an option to turn them off **per setting**. However they also suggest that there is a setting to turn off **all notifications**:

> **Notification settings**
>
> Include a setting in your app for turning all notifications on or off. Additionally, consider offering granular settings, such as letting users choose notification sounds or receiving specific notification types.

Check the page as it has much more relevant information.